# defaultdict(None)

Tags: python

I wish to have a dictionary which contains a set of state transitions. I presumed that I could do this using `states = defaultdict(None)`, but it's not working as I expected. For example:

```
states = defaultdict(None)
if new_state_1 != states["State 1"]:
    dispatch_transition()
```

I would have thought that `states["State 1"]` would return the value None and that if new_state is a bool that I would have gotten False for `new_state != states["State 1"]`, but instead I get a KeyError.

What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

`defaultdict` requires a callable as argument that provides the default-value when invoked without arguments. `None` is not callable. What you want is this:

```
defaultdict(lambda: None)
```

Comment: Not quite; `None` is actually the default argument for `defaultdict()`. But your solution is still good :)

Comment: [confused] What is the "not quite" here? did I miss an earlier edit that was not retained by the system? I don't see anything incorrect with Bjorn's explanation or answer as is.

Comment: @JasonS: My answer suggests that calling `deafultdict` with `None` as argument would not work, but it actually does.

Comment: ??? Huh? I agree None is the default argument to defaultdict(), but its effect is to cause defaultdict to raise `KeyError`s instead of producing a `None` value.

Comment: @JasonS: True, but since `None` *is* a valid argument for `defaultdict`, my first sentence (*"`defaultdict` requires a callable as argument"*) is, strictly speaking, incorrect. It's a detail, but still worth noting.

Comment: Note that with the `None` argument, it seems that the behaviour is the same as a plain `dict`, until something else is assigned to its `default_factory` instance variable. So: `defaultdict(..)` requires a callable, _or `None`_.

Comment: `None` is not the default argument for `defaultdict()`, nor is it the default argument for `dict()`.  
If one creates `sz = defaultdict()`, then try to access `sz[1]`, one can expect to get `KeyError: 1`, which is as expected from the language spec.  
When sz is initialized as `sz = defaultdict(lambda: None)`, then accessing any none existent element will not produce KeyError. `sz[1]` in this case will produce `None`, it can be verified by `sz[1] is None` producing `True`.

Answer (score 16):

In this use case, don't use `defaultdict` at all -- a plain `dict` will do just fine:

```
states = {}
if new_state_1 != states.get("State 1"):
    dispatch_transition()
```

The `dict.get()` method returns the value for a given key, or a default value if the key is not found.  The default value defaults to `None`.

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution as the answer by Björn Pollex: Instead of using `lambda: None` to obtain a zero-argument callable that returns `None`, we can supply the type of `None` (similar to the idiom `defaultdict(int)` to construct a `defaultdict` which defaults to `int()` = `0`.

The type of `None` is `NoneType`, obtainable from the `types` module:

```py
import types
defaultdict(types.NoneType)
```

If importing a new module just for this seems a bit much, we can obtain the type of `None` directly by asking about it:

```py
defaultdict(type(None))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I could also do this:

```
states = {}
...
if not new_state_1 in states or new_state_1 != states["State 1"]:
    dispatch_transition()
```

But I much prefer the defaultdict method.