# More Efficient Way of Reading Large List of dicts

Tags: python, optimization, data-structures, dictionary, mutagen

For my project I use the mutagen library to read ID3 tags from 5000+ mp3 files. After reading them I construct the following objects using them.

```
    class Track:
    def __init__(self, artist, title, album=None):
        self.artist = artist
        self.title = title
        self.album = None

    def __str__(self):
        return "Track: %s : %s" % (self.artist,self.title, )

    def set_album(self,album):
        self.album = album

class Album:
    def __init__(self, artist, title, year='', genre='', tracks=None):
        self.artist = artist
        self.year = year
        self.genre = genre
        self.title = title 
        self.tracks = []

    def __str__(self):
        return "Album: %s : %s [%d]" % (self.artist,self.title,len(self.tracks))

    def add_track(self,track):
        self.tracks.append(track)
```

The problem is some files are missing some required tags(title missing,artist missing, or both), causing KeyValueError

```
 #'TALB' (album title), 'TIT2' (track title), 'TPE1' (artist), 'TDRC' (year), and 'TCON' (genre)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.lower().endswith(e):
                fullname = os.path.join(root, filename)
                try:
                    audio = mutagen.File(fullname)
                    track = Track(audio['TPE1'],audio['TIT2'])
                    album = Album(audio['TPE1'], audio['TALB'], audio['TDRC'], audio['TCON'])
                excpet Exception as e:
                                print "Error on %s. %s " % (filename,type(e).__name__)
```

This loads all the files that have all the tags, which is not good enough.
I solved this problem by using ifs, it works fine and is fast enough. However I wonder if there is a better way of handling this.

Comment: dic.get(key) is slower

Comment: how to conclude `dic.get(key) is slower`

Comment: There's likely a much better way to achieve what you desire but since you gave us no context, this question is incomplete. For example `process(data)` is completely independent of what keys are not set.

Comment: I edited the question to illustrate exactly what I'm trying to do.I will be sure to provide more context next time I ask optimization related problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *default* value can be an empty string instead of `None` you could use a defaultdict.

```
>>> 
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(str)
>>> d['a'] = 'data'
>>> d['b'] = 1
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'str'>, {'a': 'data', 'b': 1})
>>> a = d['a']
>>> b = d['b']
>>> c = d['c']
>>> a, b, c
('data', 1, '')
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'str'>, {'a': 'data', 'c': '', 'b': 1})
>>>
```

Comment: Or if you need the default to be None, a [quick search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886355/defaultdictnone) came up with this obvious solution ```d = defaultdict(lambda: None)```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [`dict.get()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
process(data.get('a'), data.get('b'), data.get('c'), data.get('d'))
```

This is similar to doing `dict[key]`, except instead of raising a KeyError, it will `return None`, or it can return the second parameter passed (default is None).

It's similar to:

```
try:
    blah = data['a']
except ValueError:
    blah = None
```

Or:

```
if 'a' in data:
    blah = data['a']
else:
    blah = None
```

Comment: Is it similar to one or the other? They have wildly different performance characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data.get("a")` - this will return the value of `data["a"]` if `a` is present as a key in `data`, otherwise it will return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

```
a = data['a'] if 'a' in key else None
```

is equivalent to this more concise (and more efficient) statement:

```
a = data.get('a')
```

---

You might also consider just passing `data` in to `process`:

```
process(data)
```

---

Finally, there are also "slick" ways of doing this, which probably aren't warranted here, but fyi something along these lines might serve you:

```
process(**data)
```

Comment: `process(**data)` isn't exactly the same thing. That's equivalent to `process(a='data', b='data'`, etc

Comment: True.  Not the same, but (possibly) better for what(ever) OP is doing.